# Shunt trips cross compatibility

Tags: circuit-protection

If you are using a molded case circuit breaker with the specs listed below, is it possible to interchange shunt trips as long as they have the same specifications? They seem to be vendor specific. Currently, I am using a Gladiator GCBX4-SHT-24VDC shunt trip for the Gladiator GCB400S-3FF300LL. However, with lead times being an issue it is not possible to get the Gladiator GCBX4-SHT-24VDC shunt trip that I had previously had specified. Also replacing the breaker is not an option. Thus, I have been looking for a compatible replacement for the Gladiator GCBX4-SHT-24VDC.

| **Circuit Breaker Brand** | Gladiator GCB400S-3FF300LL |
| --- | --- |
| Type | *Molded* Case |
| Circuit Type | Feeder and Branch |
| Frame Size | 400A Frame |
| Amperage Rating | 300 A |
| Voltage Rating | 600 VAC/ 600 DC |
| Poles | 3 |
| Trip Type | Fixed Thermal/ Fixed magnetic |
| Interrupting Rating | 35kA @480 VAC |
| Mounting | Panel |

| Shunt Trip Brand | Gladiator GCBX4-SHT-24VDC |
| --- | --- |
| Mounting | Left Side |
| Coil Voltage | 24VAC/VDC |
| Connection | Screw Terminals |

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Do you want a 600 VAC/ 600 DC 300A shunt to work with 24VAC/VDC or vice versa?  You need to provide a lot more info to make this answerable.

Answer (score 1):

I would always advise using the manufacturer's recommended and approved accessories for each type of equipment.

In the particular case of shunt trips, I would be worried about dimensional fit and tolerances, and mechanical force output.

Protection equipment is safety critical and usually worth doing correctly.

Comment: That is what I advised the customer, but they apparently need something to get their equipment working properly. Thus, I was told to find a compatible shunt trip for this breaker. Looking around it does not appear that simply finding a compatible shunt trip is the answer.